# What does setcode mean and how to catch errors inside it?

Tags: ruby, puppet, facter

I've written the following fact. The external command sometimes throws an error, which I want to catch. I've found many examples of how to catch an error using `begin`...`end` block. Unfortunately none of these concern the `setcode do`...`end` block. In fact, I cannot find any reference about the `setcode`. Can anyone shed a little light on this?

```
Facter.add(:docexists) do
  setcode do
    cryptdevice = File.read("/home/adam/.cryptdevice")
    if `cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /home/adam/klucz.bin #{cryptdevice} crypt-tmp`
      tmp = `cryptsetup luksClose crypt-tmp`
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's wrong with `begin-rescue-end` block inside the block passed into `setcode` method?

Comment: `setcode` is the DSL from `Facter` and has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you expect error from

```
if `cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /home/adam/klucz.bin #{cryptdevice} crypt-tmp`
```

line. Then the `begin-rescue-end` block should work:

```
Facter.add(:docexists) do
  setcode do
    begin
      cryptdevice = File.read("/home/adam/.cryptdevice")
      if `cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /home/adam/klucz.bin #{cryptdevice} crypt-tmp`
        tmp = `cryptsetup luksClose crypt-tmp`
        true
      else
        false
      end
    rescue => e
      # handle error
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks a bit clearer: `result = (\`cryptsetup…\` rescue false) && \`cryptsetup …\``…

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah, but works only if OP doesn't want to handle the error but only return `false` in case if it.